# Display [h]:mm numberformat with comma separator for thousands of hours

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way of formatting a value to display hours and minutes with the `ThousandsSeparator` to improve readability on a large count of hours?

e.g. if I have a value of

> 1771.95

which displays as

> 42526:48

(using [h]:mm)

Can I get this to display as

> 42,526:48

without actually manipulating the value in the cell?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: @TomSharpe - FYI and due to your comment *"I don't think so"* you might be interested in my work around solution to display a comma separator for thousands of hours :-)

Comment: Neat solution IMHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Possible work around**

Though there's no way to modify numberformats directly to display the `ThousandsSeparator` in hour values , you might consider using comments instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range, info$, temp
    For Each cell In Target
        On Error GoTo OOPS
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Select Case cell.Value2
            Case Is > 1000
                cell.ClearComments
                temp = Split(Format(cell.Value2, "hh:mm"), ":")
                info = Format(Int(cell) * 24# + _
                       Int((cell - Int(cell)) * 24#), _
                       "#" & Application.ThousandsSeparator & "##0") & _
                       Application.ThousandsSeparator & _
                       temp(1) & " hours"
                cell.AddComment info
        End Select
OOPS:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next cell
End Sub
```

**Example result**

`1771.95` displaying comment as `42,526.48 hours`

Comment: This is a great idea...! Not exactly what I had in mind but actually probably a more useful approach as it saves me using a routine to actually change the values in the cells when switching them between decimals and times. Thank you :)