# How to set a custom numberformat for an alphanumeric cell value?

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

I have a spreadsheet where job numbers are stored in the first column. The job numbers always take the format of a number followed by a letter followed by 7 numbers.

I already have validation routines to check the first digit is a number, the second digit one of the allowed letters, the remaining 7 digits are all numbers and the total length of the job number is 9.  Since the job numbers are being used to compare to thousands of entries in a database where the data is stored in the format 1A12354501 I have to keep my stored values in the cell in the exact same format.

However for readability, I would like to make a custom format that makes the value appear as 1A-12345-01 which is the norm that all employees use when referring to job numbers.

I have tried several iterations of the custom number format using #@-#####-## but Excel wont accept any custom numberformat that I have tried. I believe the issue is the use of the dashes.  I have also tried using underscores instead of dashes, but no luck.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58854992/display-hmm-numberformat-with-comma-separator-for-thousands-of-hours/58883149#58883149) might give you some ideas for a possible workaround formatting related comments instead of formatting the cells themselves. Of course depending on the relevant data size - would appreciate feedback.

Comment: Can I propose `=LEFT(A1,2)&"-"&MID(A1,3,5)&"-"&RIGHT(A1,2)` as the solution? my best ref for formatting >> https://exceljet.net/articles/custom-number-formats

Comment: Hi p._phidot_  I am not trying to change the value in the cell, just how the cell displays the value using custom number formatting. It's analogous to formatting a phone number in a cell that looks like (123) 456-7890 but the value actually stored in the cell is 1234567890